# Problem when converting between bases and formating the output

Tags: php, hex, decimal

The objective is to convert a dec base number between 0 and 255 into a hex base number. The hex base number has to be written in a form XX. So eg 60_10=3c_16, but also 5_10=05_16.

For example:

Number 60 in dec base is 3c in hex base.

The following code works:

```
<?php
echo dechex(60);
?>
```

The output is: 3c

Bingo.

And now: Why is the output of the following code 03 instead of 3c? What can I do to make it 3c?

```
<?php
$br=60;
echo sprintf("%02x", dechex($br));
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

### Proper usage

See https://www.php.net/sprintf

It works when you pass the **dec** value to the function.

```
<?php
echo sprintf('%02x', 60);
```

### Output

```
3c
```

Answer (score 1):

When you use

```
sprintf("%02x", dechex($br));
```

with `3c` (the result of `dechex()`), the `x` in the format indicates

> x The argument is treated as an integer and **presented** as a hexadecimal
> number (with lowercase letters).

so it expects an integer and will convert this to `3`.

`x` does the conversion for you and no need for the `dechex`.....

```
echo sprintf("%02x", $br);
```